# What happen when you store something greater than 32 bits on STM32?

Tags: stm32, embedded

A couple of questions regarding the word size:
STM32 series have 32-bit wide words.

- Considering that, what happens when we try to store something more than 32 bits or even `uint64_t` for instance? I gave it a try and defined `uint64_t a = 4294967299;` and what I see in the memory is  `00000003`. What does that mean? Is it truncating?
- an address stores 32 bits, isn't it? then why do I see in the resultant bytes (`0x00000003`) stored at `&a` different addresses every byte? so from MSB, `0x00` is at `0x20017FE8`, the second byte `0x00` is at `0x20017FE9`, ... and the last `0x3` is at `0x20017FEA`. 
  Shouldn't each set of 32 bits have a distinct address?

**Edit:**

a side question: SRAM is a part of the MCU (which contains the cortex Mx processor). Is little/big endian related to the processor or the memory? The value that I see in memory seems to be big endian but according to the RM, it's little endian

Tried this code out to test the endianness:

```
uint64_t a = 0x00008a5d78456301;
uint32_t b = (uint32_t) a;    // 0x78456301
```

shouldn't `b` store the first 32 bits (from smallest address) instead of the latter 32?

Any visuals would help a lot.

Comment: 4294967299 = 0x0000_0001_0000_0003. STM32 CPUs are little-endian. A 64bits integer will occupy 8 bytes in memory. For example, from 0x20017FE8 to 0x20017FEF. Bytes in memory will be 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 (from ...FE8 to ...FEF)

Comment: Something is not right. uint64_t should be able to store that number. I think you have made a mistake in interpreting or displaying the memory contents. What happens behind the scenes is that two 32 bit registers are ganged together to make a 64 bit register. So in order to see the actual value stored in memory you need to look at both registers.

Comment: The C language has various  rules about type promotions, and sometimes it may happen that you accidentally truncate a number before it finds its way into a 64 bit variable type. But that simple direct assignment should work.

Comment: @mkeith so I do see: `0x20017FE8  00000003 00000001` in the memory so I guess that's what you mean by ganging together to make a 64 bit register?

Comment: `Shouldn't each set of 32 bits have a distinct address?` The addresses are for **bytes**, so each **byte** will have a *distinct address*.

Comment: maybe i'm misterpreting but take this as an example: https://imgur.com/a/38IP8i7
it's a 16-bit word and each address can store 16 bits.

Comment: Addressibility and data alignment is really a large topic. But C code has to behave in a certain way. On most processors/compilers each byte (octet) is individually adressable but you don't know what the compiler is doing behind the scenes to make that work. There are some platforms (DSP's, maybe) where the smallest addressable memory area is 32 bits wide. So a "char" will actually be 32 bits, and so will plain "int". Often on 32 bit platforms, 32 bit addresses must be divisible by 4. You can't say uint_32_t* pFoo = 0x00112233; *pFoo = 0. It will cause an alignment violation.

Comment: It is almost like the REAL address is 30 bits, and the least significant two bits of the address are the byte selector. Byte reads can be any address. uint16_t must read from even address. And uint32_t must read from address divisible by 4. This is not universal but it is typical.

Comment: In your edit, `0x78456301` are the first 32 bits of `a`. They are the lesser significant bits and are therefore stored in the lower memory addresses in a little-endian machine.

Comment: @brhans ah, since it's little endian, so the CPU arranges the bytes such that the LSB is at the lowest address. Regarding the addresses being different for each byte, it has to do with byte addressing memory? I had an intuition that the address would be per the word size

Answer (score 5):

Memory addresses are byte addresses. A word is made up of multiple bytes. An STM32 can (with some caveats) read 4 bytes (32 bits) at once, but each of those bytes has a separate address.

When you declare a uint64_t, you get an 8-byte (64-bit) variable. You're only looking at the lower four bytes, so what you see is correct. 4,294,967,299 in hexadecimal is:

```
0x00000001_00000003
```

If the variable is stored at address 0x20017000, the bytes will be:

```
+------------+------------+
|  Address   | Byte value |
+------------+------------+
| 0x20017000 | 0x03       |
| 0x20017001 | 0x00       |
| 0x20017002 | 0x00       |
| 0x20017003 | 0x00       |
| 0x20017004 | 0x01       |
| 0x20017005 | 0x00       |
| 0x20017006 | 0x00       |
| 0x20017007 | 0x00       |
+------------+------------+
```

This is for a little-endian CPU. If you add 1 to your uint64_t, it should increment the first byte (the one at 0x20017000).

If you try a larger number like 10^17, you should get:

```
0x01634578_5D8A0000

+------------+------------+
|  Address   | Byte value |
+------------+------------+
| 0x20017000 | 0x00       |
| 0x20017001 | 0x00       |
| 0x20017002 | 0x8a       |
| 0x20017003 | 0x5d       |
| 0x20017004 | 0x78       |
| 0x20017005 | 0x45       |
| 0x20017006 | 0x63       |
| 0x20017007 | 0x01       |
+------------+------------+
```

If you do a 32-bit read from address 0x20017000, you'll see 0x5D8A0000. This is expected and intentional -- the CPU doesn't know what you're storing in that memory!

Endianness is a property of the CPU. (The SRAM probably doesn't do byte addressing at all -- it reads and writes whole memory words at a time.) Cortex-Ms don't load or store more than 32 bits in once access, so it would be up to the compiler how to order the two halves of the 64-bit value in SRAM. You might have a big-endian CPU (although those are pretty rare), but the compiler could still put the lower 32 bits first in memory. In that case, you might see something like:

```
0x01634578_5D8A0000

+------------+------------+
|  Address   | Byte value |
+------------+------------+
| 0x20017000 | 0x5d       |
| 0x20017001 | 0x8a       |
| 0x20017002 | 0x00       |
| 0x20017003 | 0x00       |
| 0x20017004 | 0x01       |
| 0x20017005 | 0x63       |
| 0x20017006 | 0x45       |
| 0x20017007 | 0x78       |
+------------+------------+
```

A fully big-endian 64-bit value (big-endian byte order and word order) would go like this:

```
0x01634578_5D8A0000

+------------+------------+
|  Address   | Byte value |
+------------+------------+
| 0x20017000 | 0x01       |
| 0x20017001 | 0x63       |
| 0x20017002 | 0x45       |
| 0x20017003 | 0x78       |
| 0x20017004 | 0x5d       |
| 0x20017005 | 0x8a       |
| 0x20017006 | 0x00       |
+------------+------------+
```

Note that, while the CPU can do byte addressing just fine, JTAG debuggers may handle it poorly. If you're looking at a memory window in an IDE, the IDE is probably doing 32-bit reads and manually splitting up the bytes afterward. Try having the CPU store each byte in a separate 32-bit variable, then look at those variables in the memory window to see what's really going on.

**EDIT:** Your code is wrong. This:

```
uint32_t b = (uint32_t)a;
```

casts `a` to a uint32_t, which just truncates it to 32 bits. If you want to see what's in memory, you can do:

```
uint32_t *addr = (uint32_t *)&a;
uint32_t w0 = a[0];  // == *a
uint32_t w1 = a[1];  // == *(a + 1)
```

This will read 32 bits from the address of `a` (let's say it's 0x20017000), and 32 bits from the word after that in memory (0x20017004). If you want to read the bytes, the simplest way is:

```
uint8_t *addr = (uint8_t *)&a; //If this is 0x20017000...
uint32_t b0 = addr[0]; //address 0x20017000
uint32_t b1 = addr[1]; //address 0x20017001
uint32_t b2 = addr[2]; //address 0x20017002
uint32_t b3 = addr[3]; //address 0x20017003
uint32_t b0 = addr[4]; //address 0x20017004
uint32_t b1 = addr[5]; //address 0x20017005
uint32_t b2 = addr[6]; //address 0x20017006
uint32_t b3 = addr[7]; //address 0x20017007
```

Remember, when you do pointer arithmetic in C, the size of the data type is taken into account. So if `a` is a uint32_t, then `&a + 1` is 32 bits (4 bytes) later in memory. If it's a uint8_t, then `&a + 1` is 8 bits (1 byte) later in memory.

As for why your CPU uses byte addresses instead of word addresses... By definition, a byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory. If each memory address held 32 bits, then a byte would be 32 bits on that system. Bytes are 8 bits for historical reasons (meaning software compatibility). To simplify: because that way each byte could hold one character of (English) text.

(There are still some DSPs with 16-bit or 32-bit bytes, but those are special-purpose processors.)

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. so I tried creating a 64 bit variable with a value `0x00008a5d78456301` and read 32 bits into a different variable, and I see it stores `78456301`. and in the memory, I see -> https://imgur.com/a/8QbMMd0. I am sort of confused cause `78456301` should have a higher address than former 32 bits, as you stated.

Comment: That is odd. Can you edit your question to include the code you used and your method for reading the memory contents?

Comment: edited. also, why does each byte have a distinct address as opposed to every 32 bits having one distinct address? to visualize, i'm referring to https://imgur.com/a/38IP8i7. and endianness is CPU's property so when you want to write to SRAM, the processor takes care of the endianness first and then writes to it?

Comment: @Pokloha considering your test results and the information on this answer (see the illustration after "If you try a larger number like 10^17, you should get:"), I think they are consistent. Could not understand why @ AdamHaun called it "odd"

Comment: if it's supposed to be little-endian, shouldn't `b` store `0x5d8a0000` instead?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try the code I provided and let me know what you see.

Comment: @AdamHaun I really did not understand what is going on. In your figure below "If you try a larger number like 10^17, you should get:", you showed that the lower address holds LSB side of the 64-bit number. And @ Pokloha says that 32-bit reading gives right side(LSB side) of the 64 bit number. Which is perfectly consistent with your answer. Do I miss something?

Comment: @muyustan Ah, I misread Pokloha's original comment and image since he reversed the byte order from my answer. You're right; that is consistent with a normal little-endian CPU. His code is still wrong, though. :-)

Comment: @AdamHaun - nope; it truncates the first 32 bits which is `0x78456301`. I get the same answer with pointer too. "If each memory address held 32 bits, then a byte would be 32 bits on that system". Wouldn't that be true in case a byte was considered a word length?

Comment: @Pokloha Okay, you have a little-endian CPU. Casting a uint64_t to a uint32_t gives you the *lower* 32 bits. It has to -- if you store `1` in a uint64_t, casting that to a uint32_t should still give you 1.

"Byte" is always the smallest addressable unit of memory. "Word" is not always well-defined. Please make a new question if you want to know more about that.

Comment: ok @AdamHaun, now a question from me, regarding your second illustration(the one after 10^17 sentence). Let's say I declared a variable with `uint32_t var = 0x5d8a0000`. Now the memory address `0x20017000` is assigned to variable `var` let's say. In a little-endian cpu then, when I want to access content of variable `var`, is reading procedure something like the following: "stat from `0x20017000` read its content, take it as rightmost 8 bits, then jump to `0x20017001` read it and store in bits 8-15 of the register which the value of `var` is being copied, and continue like that..."

Comment: Am I on the right track?

Comment: "Bytes are 8 bits for historical reasons (meaning software compatibility)."  Historically bytes were also 9 bits with 18 and/or 36 bit words.  Fits better in an octal world, 8 fits better in an hex world.  The worlds co-existed, but this has nothing whatsoever to do with software compatibility.   bytes have been shorter and longer than those two values as well, and their history has nothing to do with holding one letter in a language.  a bit then a bite intentionally mispell it into byte.  just like nibble and an also correct spelling nybble.

Comment: With stm (push is also an stm instruction) and strd (armv7-m thumb2) you can do more than 32 bits in units of 32 bits (multiple registers).

Comment: Yes much more recently 8 bits are somewhat of a standard, but there is no governing body policing this, if a designer wishes to choose some other size, or choose to make their memory not byte addressable but some other size while retaining 8 bit bytes, that is their business.  Might make them unsuccessful, but they are quite free to do so.

Comment: i'm still a bit uncertain on the byte addressable memory and how's that relate to the history of bytes. Does it have to do with memory alignment and how padding bytes are added to align with 8 bytes?

Comment: @old_timer I fixed my wording on loads and stores; thank you. Pokloha, for more on the history of byte size, see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120126/what-is-the-history-of-why-bytes-are-eight-bits  and if you still want more, *please* make a new question; these comments are getting way too long.

Comment: @AdamHaun it does not have anything in common with the endianess. endianess matter when you **pun** the types not assign. Then regardless the computer, system, endianess,RAM and the processor `dest32 = src64 & 0xffffffff` and it is guaranteed by the C standard and is 100% portable.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint64_t a = 0x1234567811223344;
uint64_t b;
uint64_t fun0 ( void )
{
    b = 0xAABBCCDDEEFF1234;
    return(0x1001200230034004);
}

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e92d0030    push    {r4, r5}
   4:   e59f302c    ldr r3, [pc, #44]   ; 38 <fun0+0x38>
   8:   e28f5018    add r5, pc, #24
   c:   e8950030    ldm r5, {r4, r5}
  10:   e28f1018    add r1, pc, #24
  14:   e8910003    ldm r1, {r0, r1}
  18:   e8830030    stm r3, {r4, r5}
  1c:   e8bd0030    pop {r4, r5}
  20:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  24:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  28:   eeff1234    mrc 2, 7, r1, cr15, cr4, {1}
  2c:   aabbccdd    bge feef33a8 <fun0+0xfeef33a8>
  30:   30034004    andcc   r4, r3, r4
  34:   10012002    andne   r2, r1, r2
  38:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <a>:
   0:   11223344            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x11223344
   4:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

Technically a number of the cortex-m cores can be compiled little endian and/or big or selected runtime.  But I have not see a big endian one yet, and it would be unwise anyway.  ARMs native mode is little endian.  Tools default to little endian.  Not sure why it is even a question.

The sram itself doesnt matter, the sram can be configured however the chip vendor wants so long as they get and put the data on the bus correctly.

uint64_t is part of C so whether it is a PIC or AVR or something cortex-m based you still get 64 bits whatever size the memory is, whatever its endianness.  Variables are high level language notions and have nothing to do with the underlying architecture that implements them so long as it functionally implements the high level code correctly.

Smells like you are going to abuse the language if asking this question.

Answer

little endian.

The language supports 64 bit variables so the compiled code will.

Your test is endian-less it doesnt demonstrate endian-ness, but it does show the correct answer.

Comment: possible typing error in your first line of text after the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The answer chosen is wrong.

It is a C feature reagrdless the endianess. Then you store the larger data type info the smaller one it gets truncated.

in out case `dest32 = src64 & 0xffffffff`

Answer (score 0):

A side-note about integer conversions in C, is that they work on a higher abstraction level than the raw binary representation. The rule is (C11 6.3.1.3):

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.

In this case the conversion should be done "as if subtracting `UINT32_MAX+1` from the value until it is in range" - in practice this is truncating the value to 32 bits.

It doesn't matter whether you explicitly force a conversion through a cast: `uint32_t b = (uint32_t) a;`  or just do `uint32_t b = a;` and get implicit conversion through the rule of simple assignment. Either is endianess-independent and the above conversion rule applies in both cases.

Had you done something wild and crazy like `uint32_t b = *(uint32_t*)&a;` however, this *would* be endianess-dependent (and highly questionable code for several other reasons).

Answer (score -1):

4294967299(dec) = 1 0000 0003‬ (hex)

Now 64 bits are 8 bytes (8 x 8 bits = 64). Therefore the number 4294967299(dec) is divided into 8 bytes 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00.

So the last byte can't be the 4-th byte.

Comment: so you're basically saying to make 64 bit register, two 32-bit registers are sort of used to store 32 bits in each. Not sure what you meant by the last line...

Comment: @Pokloha Yes ,8 bytes are used, You said: "and the last 0x3 is at 0x20017FEA" so, the 4-th (0x03) is not the last.

Comment: that's what I referred to: https://imgur.com/a/TvYjhPV. the last byte of the first 32-bit register

Comment: Then it should be  0x07 byte,not the 0x03 byte, regardless of the register length.

Comment: Nothing common with endianess.

Comment: @P__J__ I  never mentioned about the  endianess.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič youe answer does not make too much sense. How is it related to the OP question?

Comment: @P__J__ When I posted my answer, the question was much different (see edit times). He was telling: I put the number 4294967299(dec) and I got 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, and the last 4-th byte is 0x00, does it make sense now?

Comment: explanation is wrong